# Is it possible to have better prediction on test data set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, precision, random-forest, prediction

I divided my data into 70% training and 30% test. Built a classifier using the training data, fit the model to the training data then use it to predict for the test data.

My cross validated precision score and recall score is significantly higher for the test data set. Is this possible? or does it mean I've committed a coding error?